# Подскажите как передать текст комментарий(столбец body) на кнопку "редактировать"

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как передать текст со столбца body на кнопку "Редактировать"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
код js

```
console.log(data);

function callback(a) {
    const tr = `
    <tr>
    <td> ${a.postId}</td>
    <td> ${a.id} </td>
    <td> ${a.name} </td>
    <td> ${a.email} </td>
    <td class="bubu"> ${a.body} </td>
    <td class="btn"> <a href="#">Редактировать</a> </td>
    </tr>
    `
    document.getElementById("root").innerHTML += tr;

}

data.forEach(callback);

var bubu = document.getElementsByClassName('bubu');
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

        modal.innerText = this.innerText;
        modal.style.display = 'block';

    });
}

код css

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: solid 1px black;
}

#modal {
    display: none;
    margin: 115px auto;
    width: 444px;
    height: 584px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
    position: fixed;
    visibility: visible;
}

код html

<body>
<h1>Сторінка коментарів</h1>
<div contenteditable="true" id="modal"></div>

<table>
    <thead>
    <th>postId</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>body</th>
    <th>Редактировать</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="root">

    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="./data.js"></script>
<script src="./script3.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

modal.innerText = bubu[i].innerText;